# How to capture a complete webpage using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I inject javascript code into a page user is currently viewing, on users command this script make DOM changes. At the end of this interaction user might want to save the page so that s/he can view/edit it later. I could remember the DOM changes that user made, But if the original page(at its source) is changed, I will not be able to restore this page for user. That is why I want to send the changed page to my server. I should be able to restore it completely and the page should behave exactly the way it did(including scripts and media).

Additionally I can not store media of users page at my end(resource limitation), so I guess I have to parse and modify all addresses/references/links of media to global URL/URI in various scripts(HTML/CSS/JavaScript).

Now the question is, Is there a library/framework/jquery extension that can help me achieve this objective ?

else, What is the right/professional way to do it ?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using jQuery you could try `$("html").html();`  just make sure to add the appropriate `<html>` tags when you output it again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').html()
$('head').html()
$('html').html()
```

Download firebug, and try it in the console window on this page.  I am getting what looks like the correct data back.

Answer (score 0):

Have I got It right that you are building some kind of CMS that let's the user edit entire pages (Not just seperate content blocks) in Contenteditable mode?

I would definatly advise looking at a solution like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo)/tinymce etc... Because doing it all yourself will be a terrible pain.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @Sydenam should work fine to save the whole HTML page.

Meanwhile, and this is **IMPORTANT**, I would recommend you to consider a potential **SECURITY ISSUE** here. Indeed the user can inject whatever he wants in the DOM and have you saving it, like nasty Javascript functions sending confidential information on a remote server for example.

So, in my perspective, a professional way of doing this would be to dedicate a **PART** of the DOM only to that usage, let say a `<div id='editable_div'>` that you can load using a $('#editable_div').load('your_url',parameters, etc...), and save afterward using another AJAX call.

When saving it you can parse this chunk of HTML and **make sure nothing nasty is inside** with some regexp (like  tags).

Hope it helps,

Regards,